# Is it possible to specify a controller without loosing semantic HTML in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Currently my HTML looks like this:

```
        <ul>
          <div ng-controller="productController">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.title}}</li>
          </div>
          <div ng-controller="otherProductController">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.title}}</li>
          </div>
        </ul>
```

I need something like this:

```
        <ul>
          <ng-controller name="productController">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.title}}</li>
          </ng-controller>
          <ng-controller name="otherProductController">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.title}}</li>
          </ng-controller>
        </ul>
```

Does it exist? Thanks.

PS: A nested list is not a possible solution for my case.

Comment: You can user Directives as they are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) take a look at docs her https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I've +1 Mohamed comment, directives is what you should use here

Comment: You may try to add the `ng-controller` attribute on the `li` tag directly. Not sure if this would work though, just give it a try ;)

Comment: Can you have two unordered lists?

Comment: Actualy, what's the difference between productController and otherProductController? It might be possible to achieve what you need using a single controller.

Comment: It's not possible by default, since the `ngController` directive is restricted to attributes: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L230.

Comment: + 1 for all these comments. If can say you a thing it's that the best way is to use ngRoute with a definition of controllers inside a router with templates associated to controllers... Make a generic controller for products entity and make a service to manage some specialisation.